# i want to query all the document using findById query ( Ref ObjectId ) in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

currently building notes-app project where we can save notes and can edit and delete notes also..
suddenly got stuck here... i want to query ( findById ) all the documents that matches with user id.. in this case i referenced user id as **postedBy** in Notes Schema..

**here is my user schmea or model...**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'please provide username'],   
    },
    email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'please provide email'],
    unique: true,
    index: true,   
    },   
    password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'please provide password'],
    },   
    accountCreatedAt: {
    type: String,
    default: Date,   
   },
```

})

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

export default User
```

****here goes my notes Schema and i referenced user id as ref :****

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'please provide title'],
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    text: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: [true, 'Please provide text'],
    },
    lable: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'please provide lable'],
    },
    postedBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_At', updatedAt: 'updated_At' },
  }
)

const Note = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema)

export default Note
```

**route and controller function:**

```
noteRoutes.get('/getNotesByUserID/:_id', noteController.getNotesByUserID)



export const getNotesByUserID = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params._id
    const userNotes = await Note.findById({ postedBy: id })

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        userNotes,
      },
    })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: 'error',
      data: {
        message: error.message,
      },
    })
  }
}
```

when i tried to test this in postman i'm getting the below message :

```
    *"message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ postedBy: '609554f9560327264b23d3fe' }\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Note\""*
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoose` [findById](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) method casts the `id` parameter to the type of the model's `_id` field, in your case this field is an ObjectID type.

You however are passing the `id` argument as an object `{ postedBy: '609554f9560327264b23d3fe' }` then `mongoose` tries to do the following:

```
const castId = new ObjectId({ postedBy: '609554f9560327264b23d3fe' })
```

This fails for obvious reasons.

Because `findById` is a customized method to "quickly" find documents by their `_id` field you shouldn't be using it to query a different field. In your cast you should be using `findOne` instead.

```
const userNotes = await Note.findOne({ postedBy: id })
```

Comment: thank you so much for your reply..really appreciate it.. if i use findOne instead of findById it will give me  signle document alone...i want to retrieve all the document that matches by postedBy ( ref ID)

Comment: Then you should use find instead